# UUID's have to be distinct for service , characteristic and descriptor?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make a client-server connection with the server containing one service with one characteristic which contains one descriptor. I've made the service, characteristic and descriptor have the same UUID , but when I try to write on the descriptor/characteristic (in the android app) a pop-up appears that tells me , bluetooth has to shut down becouse of some problem (not known). Is there any condition that the UUID's have to be distinct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "UU" of UUID means "Universally Unique".  The UUID is describing the type of data, though, so you can have 2 characteristics with the same UUID if both are providing the same sort of data.  (ex 2 thermometers)  I think descriptors are supposed to have UUID's dictated by the standard (so you know they're descriptors).

So, the service, characteristic, and descriptor should all have different UUID's.